# How do I delete rows from table with self reference foreign key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cascade

In Sql Server 2012 I have an employee table.
as follows

```
 table {id, managerId, name}
```

And the table has a foreign key between ManagerId and Id.

I want to delete all the people "John".

Problem is that i get a foreign key exception (using ef, and cascade delete).
How do I delete rows from table with self reference foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

OK suppose you have a manager named John. You can't delete him because you have related records for his employees.

Your first step is to update the employee records for managers you intend to delete to either have no manager or move them to a new manager. Then you can delete managers who are named John.